# Eclipse plug-in development - unit testing e4 parts

Tags: unit-testing, eclipse-plugin, e4

I am trying to test an Eclipse plug-in with a E4 style view. I have created a test class inside a JUnit plug-in Test run configuration. But I'm struggling to even open the view. The old e3 way was to use the following snippet to open views:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow()
.getActivePage().showView("some view id")
```

In e4, we can use a `EPartService` ([documentation](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fe4%2Fui%2Fworkbench%2Fmodeling%2FEPartService.html)) instead. However, I'm not sure how to access it. Trying to inject it does not work. This is what I have tried:

```
public class MyTest {

@Inject EPartService partService;

@Test
public void testOne() {
// partService is still null here...
```

I've also tried adding the @PostConstruct annotation to the test method, with no luck. Shouldn't this work, since it is running as a JUnit plug-in test, which I assume has an Eclipse context with a part service ready?

According to [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4Testing/article.html) article, it should also be possible to create a `Display` class and an associated Shell, which can be passed to the view's `createPartControl` method. I have tried this in the test method as well:

```
    Display display = Display.getCurrent();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    IEclipseContext context = EclipseContextFactory.create();
    IPartService partService = mock(IPartService.class);
    context.set(IPartService.class, partService);
    context.set(Composite.class, shell);
    view = ContextInjectionFactory.make(InspView.class, context);
    shell.open();
```

I need the IPartService (not to be confused with the EPartService...) because the view needs it. This actually works. But, as you can see, I need to mock an IPartService and hand it to the Eclipse context. This does not give me what I want. Instead, I want an Eclipse context with all the services instantiated. Is this possible? Which approach is the most correct? Using Display+Shell, or EPartService?

Thanks!

UPDATE:
It is possible to open the part using the following:

```
EPartService partService = 
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(EPartService.class);
partService.showPart(VIEW_ID, PartState.ACTIVATE);
```

Is that a good approach?

Comment: e4 doesn't have views - just parts. Something that uses IPartService doesn't sound like e4 code which doesn't support that. Are you sure this is not just 3.x compatibility mode code which you would test the old way?

Comment: You need to confirm if this view is 3.x compatibilty mode - does the view exend `ViewPart` - if so it is 3.x and should be opened the old way. EPartService on its own will not set up a 3.x view correctly.

Comment: The view is just a pojo, so it's e4, yes. It gets a IPartService injected and uses it to listen to part events about my editor. This currently works because the editor extends EditorPart (e3). However, I would like to migrate the editor to e4 as well, and then I guess the part listener won't work..? This is perhaps another question.